# iOS storyboards instantiate viewController and IBAction

Tags: ios, storyboard

I may go mad very soon.

This is the reason:
- I started up with Single View Application project with storyboards. Then I set the view controller class name in the storyboard for my viewController. 
- Next step I created one pointer for this viewController in AppDelegate method ...didFinishLaunchingWithOpt... and filled it up by calling [myStoryboards instantiate...]. It works pretty good because I can call method like [vc1 setMyName] which does smthng like self.myName = @"Johnny"; 
- But here it comes. When I create IBAction method joined with button, this method doesn't know anything about "Johhny". And this is because I'm in another instance. When I check the address of "self" it is another one...

WhyWhyWhy??? Please help, how can I use still the same object - the one instantiated in AppDelegate by storyboards and the one from storyboards in "interface builder".

Thank you.

---

Oh my. I think I really underestamated it...
When we were talking about getting pointer of other viewControllers from storyboard...

I have initialViewController got by calling rootViewContr... And another one connected with segue (modal) where is UITableView. A get data on rootViewController and I want to show them on the other one in the list (UITableView). So I call segue (performSegueWithIdentifier), the other controller is shown but the list is clear. Because the method I call is working with tableView variable which is null :/ Because, again, I'm in another object. That is because I call that method storyboard instantiate... How can I get exactly the same viewController which I'm working in storyboard with. It is quite confusing for me :/

I read something about prepareForSegue and getting the pointer by destinationViewController but that is not what exactly I want. I need the pointer before I call segue method and the viewController is shown...

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've set up your initial view controller properly in the storyboard, you don't need to assign it to the windows `rootViewController` property in `-applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` as this is done for you automatically. It sounds like you're creating a second instance. To access the original instance setup by the storyboard simply do this in `-applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
InitialViewController *viewController = (InitialViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
viewController.myName = @"Johnny";
```

Comment: GREAT! Thank you. That's it. I knew I was working with second instance. But didn't know how to avoid it.

OK. So similar question using new facts. What about situation when I have two viewControllers. Is there a chance to get the pointer in the way you described?

Comment: Only the view controller marked as the 'Initial View Controller' in the storyboard will be instantiated by the time `-applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is sent. If you need references to other view controllers, you need to instantiate them with the methods on `UIStoryboard`.

Comment: Yes. I get it. And it works! So really big "thank you" to you

Comment: You're welcome! Nothing says thank you like a big green checkmark though... ;)